# How to get the installed application location in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a WPF application in my application i'm specifying the default path for the installation location suppose, XYZ is my application, "C:\MyApplication\XYZ\" this is my specified default location where my application gets installed, my application creates a folder dynamically which will be created during the installation of the application in the installed directory, i want when user uninstalls the application then my entire folder(XYZ) has to be deleted i tried many ways but i'm not getting it Please any one give suggestion it will helps me a lot.

Here is what i have tried :-

```
string filepath = String.Format(@"data\local", Environment.CurrentDirectory);
public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
    try
    {               
        base.Uninstall(savedState);
        // If i Hard code this i.e if i give direct path(C:\MyApplication\XYZ\) 
        // then it's getting deleted but if user installs application in other 
        // location it gets fail.
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(
          filepath, 
          Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents); 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `var filepath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\data\local";` ?

Answer (score 0):

Application installation is *not* something that we need to manage manually in the .NET Framework. It provides multiple installation options, so you do *not* have to manually install or uninstall your applications. The two main installation options the Framework are:

1. [ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.ASPX)
2. [Setup Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/996a3fxs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

As there is far to much to discuss here, please follow the links to find out more.